# Doubly transitive subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I have a basic question about doubly transitive subgroups of $S_n$.

> Let $G$ be a doubly transitive subgroup of $S_n$ such that $G$
>   contains a simple transposition. Why does it follow that $G=S_n$?

This fact is freely used in the article "Galois groups of enumerative problems" by Joe Harris, but without any reference. So I assume that it is a relatively straightforward fact, but a proof is evading me.

Let me recall few definitions for the sake of context. If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, the action of $G$ on $X$ is called *transitive* if for every $x, y\in X$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot x=y$. The action is called *doubly transitive* if for any two pairs $(x, y)$ and $(x', y')$ with $x\neq y$ and $x'\neq y'$, there is a $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot x = x'$ and $g\cdot y=y'$. In other words, we can use an element of $G$ to move any distinct pair to any distinct pair. Some authors use the terminology *2-transitive* for this concept.

So, when we say a *doubly transitive subgroup of $S_n$*, we are thinking of the natural action of the subgroup on $n$ letters (or symbols, etc.), say $X=\{1, 2, ..., n\}$. This is an action "inherited" from $S_n$. Finally, a *simple transposition* just means a permutation on $X$ that switches $i$ and $j$ ($i\neq j$) but fixes everything else.

Comment: If $G$ contains a transposition, say $(i,j)$ and $G$ is doubly transitive, then for any distinct $k,l \in X$, there is a $g \in G$ mapping $i \to k$ and $j \to l$, and then  the conjugate of $(i,j)$ under $g$ is equal to $(k,l)$. So $G$ contains all transpositions, and hence $G=S_n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you so much. So slick! Feel free to post it in the answer box so that I can accept it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much for the answer.. which I have been searching for a long time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ contains a transposition $\sigma=(i\ j)$.  Then for any distinct $i',j'\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, there exists some $\tau\in G$ such that $\tau(i)=i'$ and $\tau(j)=j'$, since $G$ is doubly transitive.  Now just notice that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ is the transposition $(i'\ j')$.  Since $i'$ and $j'$ were arbitrary, this means $G$ contains all transpositions.  Since transpositions generate $S_n$, this means $G=S_n$.

More generally, this shows that if $G$ contains a transposition and $N(G)$ is doubly transitive, then $G=S_n$.